# Google IntelliJ java style: changing 2-space indentation to 4-space indentation

Tags: intellij-idea, code-formatting

I have installed `google-java-format` plugin for `IntelliJ` and I have enabled the plugin. When I format the code, my java code gets indented by 2 spaces. How do i change the google java formatter plugin setting to change to 4 spaces?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to change to 4-space indentations by selecting the **Android Open Source Project (AOSP) style** in the google-java-format plugin settings:

[image]

It looks like the only difference between the two styles is that AOSP doubles the spacing to 4 instead of 2:
https://github.com/google/google-java-format/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/google/googlejavaformat/java/JavaFormatterOptions.java#L37

Comment: Heads up: since May 2019, AOSP formatting may also affect the import sort order. See [here](https://github.com/coveooss/fmt-maven-plugin/issues/70) and [here](https://github.com/google/google-java-format/issues/319). When I tested this in IntelliJ though, AOSP import orders look the same as Default Java.

Answer (score 5):

First I disabled the `IntelliJ` google-java-format plugin.Downloaded `IntelliJ-java-google-style.xml` from [here](https://github.com/google/google-java-format) and modified indent size property as below. After importing this style in IntelliJ, I am able to indent to 4 spaces. To import the code style XML, please refer to this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/copying-code-style-settings.html)

```
  <codeStyleSettings language="CSS">
    <indentOptions>
      <option name="INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="CONTINUATION_INDENT_SIZE" value="4" />
      <option name="TAB_SIZE" value="4" />
    </indentOptions>
  </codeStyleSettings>
```

Comment: You can also import style and then go to settings->code style and change the indent size.

Comment: @Shravan Ramamurthy how to change the schema into Tab indentation?

Comment: Just in case, someone has the google java style plugin installed: it overwrites code style settings we are talking about here. I was trying to change it for a while with no success until I realized that. ;)

Comment: Be aware that the `google-java-format` plugin will style your code quite differently from [intellij-java-google-style.xml](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml).